How to create PGP Secret Key Ring File in GitHub Actions?
I have already setup GPG_PRIVATE_KEY stores the armoured PGP Private key and GPG_PASSPHRASE stores the passphrase of the private key in GitHub Actions secrets.
And the workflow configuration is as following:
name: Publish Packages to GitHub Packages with Gradle

# triggers here

jobs:
  build:
    name: Build and Publish
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      contents: read
      packages: write

    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Setup GPG TTY
        run: export GPG_TTY=$(tty)

      - name: Import PGP Private Key
        uses: crazy-max/ghaction-import-gpg@v6.1.0
        with:
          gpg_private_key: ${{ secrets.GPG_PRIVATE_KEY }}
          passphrase: ${{ secrets.GPG_PASSPHRASE }}
          trust_level: 5

      - name: Creating PGP Ring Key
        run: gpg --export-secret-keys -o ~/pgp_key.ring

But every time GitHub Actions failed at Creating PGP Ring Key, and the error reports are
gpg: key 1C30B1E1C9A2D76CF192F1DAA5D514BA5BA4B994: error receiving key from agent: Inappropriate ioctl for device - skipped
gpg: key 4E62187A7239B6C9177C3B147DC971BF735214B1: error receiving key from agent: Inappropriate ioctl for device - skipped
gpg: WARNING: nothing exported
Error: Process completed with exit code 2.


Try: GPG_TTY=$(tty) gpg --export-secret-keys -o ~/pgp_key.ring
